# My edit page showing nothing besides what already in the main.html

Tags: python, html, django, view

I'm working on a Django project making a to-do list app in my edit page nothing is showing besides what is already inside my main.html

my edit.html file

```
 {% extends 'main.html' %}


{% block container %}

<div>editor</div> 
<div>
    {% if item %}
        <form class="form-check-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="{{ item.item }}" aria-label="search" value="{{ item.item }}" name="item">
           
            <input type="hidden" value="{{item.complete}}" name="complete">
            
            <button clss="btn btn-outline-sceondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    {% endif %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

my views

```
def edit(request, list_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        item = List.objects.get(pk=list_id)

        form = ListForms(request.POST or None, instance=item)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,('Item has been Edited'))
            return redirect('home')
            #return render(request, 'home.html',{'all_item': all_item})
    else:
        item = List.objects.get(pk=list_id)
        return render(request, 'home.html',{'item': item})
```

my URLs

```
from django import views
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('delete/<list_id>', views.delete, name='delete'),
    path('crossoff/<list_id>', views.crossoff, name='crossoff'),
    path('uncrossoff/<list_id>', views.uncrossoff, name='uncrossoff'),
    path('edit/<list_id>', views.edit, name='edit'),

]
```

If you need any more information just ask me in the comment

Edit: fixed

Comment: You're rendering `home.html` and not `edit.html` in your view

Comment: ahhhhh I'm so dumb thanks a lot man it's woking now